# Entity Framework, error with the date returned

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to use Entity Framework for my API but after trying to order my list of objects by Date, a problem happen.

My objective is to scrap a web page every day, save the products in database, acces to it with my API.

As you will see under, datas are correct in SQL DB but, using Entity Framework, it will return me 2 times the same date.

My DB is :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ScrappedProducts] (
    [Domain]          VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
    [ProductId]       VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
    [ScrappedDate]    DATE            NOT NULL,
    [ProductUrl]      VARCHAR (256)   NOT NULL,
    [ProductName]     VARCHAR (200)   NOT NULL,
    [ProductBrand]    VARCHAR (200)   NOT NULL,
    [ProductType]     VARCHAR (100)   NOT NULL,
    [ProductAlcool]   DECIMAL (16, 2) NOT NULL,
    [ProductQuantity] INT             NOT NULL,
    [ProductContain]  DECIMAL (16, 2) NOT NULL,
    [ProductPrice]    DECIMAL (16, 2) NOT NULL,
    [ProductImageUrl] VARCHAR (256)   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductId] ASC, [Domain] ASC, [ScrappedDate] ASC)
);
```

My class is :

```
namespace WebScrapperAPI.Components
{
    public class Product
    {
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public DateTime ScrappedDate {get;set;}
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductUrl { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductBrand { get; set; }
        public string ProductType { get; set; }
        public decimal ProductAlcool { get; set; }
        public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }
        public decimal ProductContain { get; set; }
        public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
        public string ProductImageUrl { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My DbContext class is :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebScrapperAPI.Components;

namespace WebScrapperAPI.Data
{
    public class ScrapperDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> ScrappedProducts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=tcp:xxx,xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";


            var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddConsole(); // Ajouter la journalisation sur la console
                builder.AddFilter(DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name, LogLevel.Information); // Filtrer les logs SQL uniquement
            });
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
                .UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
                .LogTo(Log, new[] { DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name }, LogLevel.Information);
        }
        private void Log(string t)
        {
            File.WriteAllText("test.txt", t);
        }
    }
}
```

DB values :

```
Auchan  0067c78b-7b53-4e2a-b655-d9c071a5ca87    2023-07-18  https://www.auchan.fr/valauria-muscat-vin-doux-naturel-de-rivesaltes-aop-15-5/pr-C1211479   Muscat vin doux naturel de Rivesaltes AOP   VALAURIA    Liquor  15.50   1   75.00   6.65    /static/images/pixel.png

Auchan  0067c78b-7b53-4e2a-b655-d9c071a5ca87    2023-07-19  https://www.auchan.fr/valauria-muscat-vin-doux-naturel-de-rivesaltes-aop-15-5/pr-C1211479   Muscat vin doux naturel de Rivesaltes AOP   VALAURIA    Liquor  15.50   1   75.00   6.65    /static/images/pixel.png
```

Entity Framework values :

```
{
    "domain": "Auchan",
    "scrappedDate": "2023-07-18T00:00:00",
    "productId": "0067c78b-7b53-4e2a-b655-d9c071a5ca87",
    "productUrl": "https://www.auchan.fr/valauria-muscat-vin-doux-naturel-de-rivesaltes-aop-15-5/pr-C1211479",
    "productName": "Muscat vin doux naturel de Rivesaltes AOP",
    "productBrand": "VALAURIA",
    "productType": "Liquor",
    "productAlcool": 15.5,
    "productQuantity": 1,
    "productContain": 75,
    "productPrice": 6.65,
    "productImageUrl": "/static/images/pixel.png"
  },
  {
    "domain": "Auchan",
    "scrappedDate": "2023-07-18T00:00:00",
    "productId": "0067c78b-7b53-4e2a-b655-d9c071a5ca87",
    "productUrl": "https://www.auchan.fr/valauria-muscat-vin-doux-naturel-de-rivesaltes-aop-15-5/pr-C1211479",
    "productName": "Muscat vin doux naturel de Rivesaltes AOP",
    "productBrand": "VALAURIA",
    "productType": "Liquor",
    "productAlcool": 15.5,
    "productQuantity": 1,
    "productContain": 75,
    "productPrice": 6.65,
    "productImageUrl": "/static/images/pixel.png"
  }
```

Edit : My Query

```
public static IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
{
    var products = new List<Product>();
    using (var context = new ScrapperDBContext())
    {
        products = context.ScrappedProducts.ToList();
    }
    return products;
}
```

Comment: Add the Query that produces this result.

Comment: Edited :

        public static IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            var products = new List<Product>();
            using (var context = new ScrapperDBContext())
            {
                products = context.ScrappedProducts.ToList();
            }
            return products;
        }

Comment: So, they are identical, with the exception of the day: 18 vs 19, but in your result both entries have 18th as date...  interesting! But I have no idea how that could come to pass, I am afraid.

Comment: its possible that the `productId` is treated as a unique key. try turning up the logging to see what query was made

Comment: you should have a `ScappedProduct` entity, not reuse the one from projects

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods, here is my request : "SELECT [s].[ProductId], [s].[Domain], [s].[ProductAlcool], [s].[ProductBrand], [s].[ProductContain], [s].[ProductImageUrl], [s].[ProductName], [s].[ProductPrice], [s].[ProductQuantity], [s].[ProductType], [s].[ProductUrl], [s].[ScrappedDate]
FROM [ScrappedProducts] AS [s]
WHERE LOWER([s].[ProductType]) = @__ToLower_0", doesn't seems to do something special, except the "WHERE" i used to accelerate my tests

Comment: @DanielA.White, reuse the one from projects ? I created this one for this solution, don't understand what you mean

Comment: Please post the code for the context class.

Comment: Post the information in the question itself. Neither databases nor EF return JSON. Are you sure the bug isn't in whatever you used to generate that string? That `WHERE LOWER([s].[ProductType]) = @__ToLower_0"` is a serious bug by the way because it *prevents* the server from using indexes. If you want case-insensitive searches, use the correct collation. In SQL Server, the default is case-*in*sensitive

Comment: Are there *more* than 2 matching results with the same date and type perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, 
No, either DB or EF return Json but "API web ASP.NET Core" did, if you have an "APIController" with your [HttpGet] attribute and a "IEnumerable<Product>" as return, it will.
"@__ToLower_0" is just the variable created from EF to make the filter and the where isn't a bug, i need it to filter my datas...
Don't hesitate to correct me but i don't see any bug here

Comment: No, there is no "2 matching results with the same[...]", all dates are diffrents cause it's a PK, it's not possible as you can see in my DB, dates are differents, it's only when i'm getting datas, even by placing a spy in code, dates goes to "18/07/2023"

Comment: EF won't add `WHERE LOWER([s].[ProductType]) = @__ToLower_0` unless your own code used `x.ProductType.ToLower()=whatever`. That `ToLower()` is the bug. EF works. The question is why the application's code doesn't return what you expected. Perhaps there are more results you didn't see? Perhaps the ASP.NET Core action returned the wrong results? Right now none of the code produces the results but there's a lot of *missing* code

Comment: `dates goes to "18/07/2023"` that's a localized string, again not how dates are serialized in JSON or stored in the database.

Comment: Are the `ProductID` values in the `DB Values` snippet identical? How come the dates are different then? Is not `ProductID` the primary key?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Oh yeah i used the "ToLower()", even without it's not working or dealing anything... Not it's only this data for now. No it's not cause of ASP.NET core json returned, as i said when i'm looking into the code as debug, Date values are still bugged

Comment: And *there's* the application, and database design bug. Unless you explicitly specify otherwise, EF Core assumes `Id` or `ProductID` is the primary key of the entity, simply because that's the most common way to specify primary keys. ID is the short version of IDentity. One could make a very strong argument that the `Product` table should have a single column primary key. Otherwise it shouldn't be called `ProductID`, or the table shouldn't be `Products`. If it specifies a relation between other tables, the name should reflect that

Comment: If that problem can't be fixed, the entity should be configured to have a complex primary key, including the same columns as the database

Comment: @IchiSamaFR dates aren't bugged.

Comment: You still haven't posted the code for class `ScrapperDBContext`.

Comment: @IchiSamaFR I edited your question to remove the credentials. You posted the entire connection string. I strongly suggest you go change the credentials right now.

Comment: @IchiSamaFR what you posted verifies what I wrote. There's no configured primary key which  means `ProductID` is used as the primary key by EF Core. The table contains multiple rows for each `ProductID` though. When EF Core generates objects from the results it tracks them by their *primary key*, which means that duplicate rows (by that PK) return the same object. That's not an EF bug. ORMs like NHibernate and EF Core track *in-memory objects*, not rows. The objects' identity is their primary key, so the same PK values *must* map to the same object. Doing otherwise would be a huge bug

Comment: @JuanR, Yeah i'm stupid, anyways it's juste a tesDB, i will changed it, is okay not a big problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused because the application entity `Product` has a different primary key than the table. As no key is specified either in the class or the DbContex's `OnModelBuilding`, the property `ProductID` is used by convention.

The table though, uses `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductId] ASC, [Domain] ASC, [ScrappedDate] ASC)` which means there will always be multiple rows for the same `ProductId`. When EF sees the same PK values multiple times, it returns the same cached object.

To fix this, the composite primary key must be specified explicitly:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Product>().HasKey(p=> new {
            p.ProductId, 
            p.Domain,
            p.ScrappedDate});
    }
```

That's not a bug. The primary key is an in-memory entity's identity so the same PK values *must* return the same object. Otherwise, an application could find itself reading one object and modifying another even though they're supposed to be the same one.

ORMs like NHibernate, Entity Framework and basically everything that tracks objects instead of just mapping results, uses the PK values as the identity of objects. Their job is to give the impression of working with in-memory entities, not tables and rows. Asking for the same object by identity, should always return the same in-memory object.